# Javascript to ckeck if user enters space in the text field

Tags: javascript, textbox, space, prompt

I want a script which should *alert the user if space is entered* in the text field.I think it requires javascript.I am writing a script in which i don't want user to enter space in the text fields.

Comment: what have you done so far? what are you stuck on?

Comment: In the registration form which i have created i dont want username to be entered with spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following function worked

```
$returnValue = preg_match('/[^a-z^A-Z^0-9]/', $str, $matches);
if ($returnValue==1) 
{
    alert("spaces & symbols are not allowed");
}
```

*Note:* **It not only restricts spaces but also restricts symbols.**

Answer (score 0):

use the `match()` method of strings

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function checkForm()

    {
    var textb=document.getElementById("textbox1").value;

        if(textb.match(' ')){
           alert('Spaces not allowed!');
           return false;
        }
}
```

Comment: how will i specify which textbox to check.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function match() is shown. Can You specify where should i write this script.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {
$("textarea").keypress( function(e) {
if (e.which==32){
alert("spaces are not allowed");
}
});
});
</script>
<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: man it alerts that spaces are not allowed but space is included in textarea :(